# Delphi Font Resource

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have an application having with one TTF resource as "Font" included. I wish to use this font as Fomr Font on FormCreate event. I am not willing to extract this font to a directory and load from there. I am unable to this please help me. I am learner please do not ask for my codes.

I have used "Font Resource ID 13" and "Font Name AmarBangla.ttf". I have tried the following codes but gerting error. Here is those codes:

First One :

```
procedure TForm01.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
    Form01.font[13] := AddFontResource (LPCTSTR lpszFontName));
    Form01.font := 13;
end;
```

Second One :

```
 procedure TForm01.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
    Form01.font[13] := AddFontResource (Hinstance, MakeIntResource(13));
    Form01.font := 13;
 end;
```

Comment: If you're embarrassed to show us the code you've written, then there's probably something that we could help you to improve. There's nothing wrong with learning; the problem comes about when you're reticent and unwilling to improve.

Comment: Talk is cheap. Show me the code. :)

Comment: I have used "Font Resource ID 13" and "Font Name AmarBangla.ttf". I have tried the following codes but gerting error.
Here is those codes
First One :

    procedure TForm01.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Form01.font[13] := AddFontResource (LPCTSTR lpszFontName));
      Form01.font := 13;

Second One :
    
    procedure TForm01.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Form01.font[13] := AddFontResource (Hinstance, MakeIntResource(13));
      Form01.font := 13;

Comment: @Koushik Halder: If you add your code to your original post, you will be able to format it nicely (which is not possible in a comment).

Comment: Please tag your questions properly. We always have to retch them for you. Please start doing it right. Always include generic delphi tag and the specific version tag delphi-xe2

Comment: OK ! I have tagged my code to the original post. Please help me.

Comment: @Koushik - AddFontResource does not return a TFont, neither a font handle.. After you add your font you can use it by specifying its name `font.name:='AmarBangla'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`AddFontMemResourceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183325%28VS.85%29.aspx) function could help you, but it looks like [Microsoft forbids embedding their fonts into applications if it violates the license of the font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162511.aspx):

> An application cannot be distributed along with documents that contain embedded fonts, **nor can an application itself contain an embedded font**.

Font embedding may violate copyrights. You first need a font that allows for redistribution, and then you will need to install it on the target system along with your application. Moreover, the font's properties will tell you if they allow for embedding.